# Jmeter - How to share cookies between threads?

Tags: cookies, jmeter

According to [Jmeter spec](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), "Each JMeter thread has its own "cookie storage area". So, it means I can't use one global (top-level) HTTP Cookie Manager to share cookies between different threads.

So, the only solution I know is to store cookies as properties and extract them at the beginning of each thread.

**Q:** Is there any other way to do the same without storing cookies in files/properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to share cookies between all threads. So the solution you have tried (to manually set cookies and then extract them) should be the only one.

[Here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-cookie-manager-td544523.html) a user asked this question and has been answered this way by jMeter support:

> No. 
>   JMeter threads are intended to represent independent users, so cookies 
>   and variables are local to a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share cookies between threads, not thread groups, as per [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article:

> Received Cookies can be stored as JMeter thread variables (versions of JMeter 2.3.2+ no longer do this by default).
>
> To save cookies as variables, define the property **CookieManager.save.cookies=true**.  The names of the cookies contain the prefix "COOKIE_" before they are stored (this avoids accidental corruption of local variables).

I hope you know how to work with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

The property can be set in 2 ways:

1. As a command-line argument via -J key like:

   ```
   jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. In user.properties file. In this case it will be permanent. Restart is required to pick to property up from file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dmitri. I meant thread groups, not threads. So, can't use variables as they are processed on per-thread-group basis. However, I also tried this method before an successfully use it in some scenarios. The real reason why I asked the question was the fact that I can add Cookie Manager on the test plan level, it cause some misunderstandings. Anyway, thanks again for all your great effort. 95% of all answers in #jmeter thread on stackoverflow are yours :)

Comment: In case of groups you have to go for properties (or patch Jmeter)