# Sharing cookies between thread groups

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am working on JMeter 3.3. I will have n users and the login should be done only once but the other pages are to be executed multiple times. I found the solution as using 2 different thread groups, but its not working as I have cookies from my login.

I saw a similar usecase in: [Sharing cookie values between thread groups in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825984/sharing-cookie-values-between-thread-groups-in-jmeter) but none of the solutions worked. How to make this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter - How to share cookies between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745431/jmeter-how-to-share-cookies-between-threads)

Answer (score 0):

Could SetUp Thread Group be an answer? (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) - I mean the login (and extracting cookies to a variable) would be done in that setUp group, then your other tests in 'normal' Thread Groups - which would read that globally available variable with your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to login user only one time per iteration,than use [Once only controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller).
To share cookies between thread groups you can use [Inter-thread communication plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to perform login only once you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with the condition of `${__groovy(vars.getIteration() == 1,)}` where:

- [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - a JMeter Function allowing execution of arbitrary [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code
- `vars` - is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance providing read/write access to JMeter Variables. [`vars.getIteration()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--) method returns current [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration so the sampler(s) you put under the If Controller will be executed only once for each virtual user.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43379806/8305811 but by turning on the CookieManager.save.cookies to true and setting up the cookie manager in the test plan level.